# Computer disk or DVD disk virus

Tags: dvd, virus

*Can a disk get a virus?* I played it in my computer and another computer and a DVD recorder and it all jammed

Answer (score 3):

You might just have a DVD that's for some reason non standard. Lets break it down to a few things.

Disks can have viruses, but most modern viruses tend not to be hugely destructive - they're more interested in misusing your computer for nefarious activities such as botnets, spamming, and good old identity theft. About the only virus that's caused hardware damage i know of was [CIH/Chernobyl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIH_%28computer_virus%29), and the last outbreak was a decade ago.

By DVD recorder, do you mean an internal DVD burner in a desktop, a USB attached external DVD burner, or a standalone 'vcr' style DVD recorder?

DVD recorders DO jam, especially if a disk was for some reason damaged. Were the drive slot loaders or tray loaders? were the disks damaged in any way? If it was an external or standalone drive was there any heavy object on top of the drive? (which may cause the case to bend, and jamming to occur.

In addition, you can't change the ram on a DVD burner, short of replacing the whole board. You could possibly change the dvd transport components (IE the tray and laser).

However a virus that affects an X86 based laptop won't affect a standalone DVD drive.

I'm not sure, but i'm not convinced reinstalling windows is a solution for a stuck drive either - I'd be a little leery of any computer tech who told me that too.

Answer (score 0):

A disk (as in cd, dvd etc.) cannot "get" a virus. If the disk is filled with a file that is affected at creation it most certainly will "contain" a virus.

A harddrive can easily be affected.

If you put a disc into a dvd/cd-player in a computer that is affected with a virus the disc won't get it. However, if the disc contains a virus the computer will most likely be affected.

Do you have access to the computer the disk was made on? If so - check the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If Autorun is enabled in the OS and there is an autorun file on the root of the CD/DVD and is crafted properly, when inserted it can infect a Windows PC without the users knowledge or need of other interaction by the user.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it can get a virus.

No, it can't jam the DVD.

Comment: I burnt a disk then checked it in my dvd recorder and it jammed ( I could not get it out) and had to get a new RAM for my recorder and my laptop had to have windows reinstalled.

Comment: New "RAM" for your recorder? Not sure what you mean...

Comment: @Downvoter: Mind commenting?

Comment: Maybe the down-voter simply disagree with the "can't jam the DVD" part, or thinks that a yes/no answer is not much helpful. (Such answer could also mean the question itself is not much helpful to future readers.)